# Don't get a duplicated record on SQL

Tags: sql, greatest-n-per-group

From a select query I have the result something like this:

```
IdCompany | IdUser | ComapnyName | JobTitle
1           100      Company1      Developer
2           100      Company2      Developer
3           200      Company3      Developer
4           200      Company4      Developer
5           200      Company5      Developer
6           300      Company6      Developer
```

What I want is to get same fields but not the duplicated IdUser, for each IdUser to get only one record. I tried with DISTINCT and EXISTS but couldn't come to a solution.
This is the way I want my result to be:

```
IdCompany | IdUser | ComapnyName | JobTitle
1           100      Company1      Developer
5           200      Company5      Developer
6           300      Company6      Developer
```

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: DISTINCT is doing the job obediently, because the IdCompany is not Unique in each row, try searching the **GROUP BY** command

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A typical way of doing this uses the ANSI standard window function`row_number()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by idUser order by idUser) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```
select * from TABLE group by ´IdCompany´
```

Comment: GROUP BY CompanyName (not IdCompany) and don't forget that the order of displaying COLUMNS also effects the GROUP BY

Answer (score 1):

This should do the job provided that IdCompany is a PK or at least distinct

```
select * from table 
where IdComapny in 
(select min(IdCompany) from table
group by IdUser)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your requirement might be wrong. But This query is very close to your results. Please place the your table at in below query

```
select * from 
    (
        select  rn = ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by IdUser order by IdUser) , 
                *  
        from    YourTable
    ) B
where   rn = 1
```